# Add My location to google maps android

Tags: android, google-maps, location

hi guy can any body tell me how i can add my home address to google map so that other can identify by giving the address. i m in india. I need to do it by code in android. Hope you could understand by question if not inform me.

Thanks

Update:

hi guys what i actually need is when we go to google maps and go to mymaps after login we will be able to add some markers to the map and add a description to that location right and other also could able to see it when they search with some relavent data. I want to do that functionality from the android using the google maps api. how could i do it...

Update #2:

Hi guys i have found the answer for this question. Actually what i have been searching is Google Places API which can be used to search the near by location as well as allows me to add location to google maps so that others can find that place  when they search in google maps..

Thanks for all...

Comment: Are you asking how to get your address into Google Maps? Or how to get Google Maps to display your location on a map? Please advise

Comment: i will give the co-ordinates and assign a address to that.. And i want others to access that co-ordinates by giving the address..

Comment: You don't assign addresses to coordinates. Using Google Maps your users will input address details and will be given the geographic coordinates from Google Maps. Try to rephrase your question or ask it differently

Comment: ya but will it be possible for others to access that

Comment: Have a look at the tutorial below that @haphazard has referenced. Thats how to use Google Maps Services. While there are some variations in how others have used this service it is pretty straight forward and will provide your users the coordinates or location they are looking for based on address information they provide.

Comment: hi apesa i have re-edited my question... Hope you could understand what i m actually trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: hi haphazard i went through that tutorial its fine but what i actually need is when we go to google maps and go to mymaps after login we will be able to add some markers to the map and add a description to that location right. I want to do that functionality from the android using the google maps api. how could i do it...

Comment: and also i have edited my question...

Comment: Based on your edit, it seems like you want to save a location on our personal Google Maps account and then allow others to see it.  This will require a backend server to distribute this information.  OR you can try to get http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.com/2007/11/google-maps-allow-anyone-to-edit-your.html that working through the Google Maps API.

Comment: +1 Thanks Haphazard... Will go through the link u provided, can you explain me briefly about the first method that you prefered.

Comment: hi Haphazard... I have just found a solution to my problem and thanks for your support. What i m actually searching for is Google Places API. Thanks...

Comment: i need API v2.i refer [http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html].but my virtual device shows google play service update button.How to overcome this?